# Unable to Load Image for an Hyperlink in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html

I am working on a module in which a button/ Hyperlink should be displayed as an image instead of regular text in MVC 4 View. I have following code snippet.

```
<td>
<a href="#"  data-bind="click: $root.edit"><img src="~/Images/edit.png" /></a>
<a href="#"  data-bind="click: $root.remove"><img src="~/Images/del.png" /></a>

 <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.add"><img src="~/Images/add.png" /></a>
```

> I have all the image files added in the solution in the Images folder, but for some reasons, they are not displaying in the UI. 
>   The error I am getting is

```
"GET http://localhost:20823/~/Images/del.png 404 (Not Found) " 
"GET http://localhost:20823/~/Images/edit.png 404 (Not Found) "

"GET http://localhost:20823/~/Images/add.png 404 (Not Found) "
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Url.Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to resolve your relative path to an absolute one e.g.

```
<img src='@Url.Content("~/Images.edit.png")' />
```